# why polymer not render html markup fetched from server in json format?

Tags: html, json, django, polymer

**my custom element:**

```
<core-ajax auto method="GET" url="http://example.com/book" handleAs="json" response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
      <core-header-panel mode="cover" layout horizontal flex>   
        <div  class="core-header tall">{{articlename}}</div>
        <div  class="content" flex >
          {{response[0].content}}
        </div>
</core-header-panel>
```

content in db was stored in markdown format,it will be transformed to html markup when requested,this process was fine,i got the transformed html markup,but when it dynamically inserted into the page, the html markup wasn't rendered whereas original html tag .

**markdown to html:(i use [django-markdown-deux](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux))**

```
markdown(content)
```

**original data from db:**

```
[{"id":4,"title":"css 1","category":"CSS","articletags":["sa","asd"],"content":"*asdsdsasadsa*\r\n\r\n    sdsadsadssdsasdsa","like":0,"createtime":"2015-04-17T05:58:01Z"}]
```

**parsed data from db:**

```
[{"id":4,"title":"css 1","category":"CSS","articletags":["sa","asd"],"content":"<p><em>asdsdsasadsa</em></p>\n\n<pre><code>sdsadsadssdsasdsa\n</code></pre>\n","like":0,"createtime":"2015-04-17T05:58:01Z"}]
```

and result is :

[image]
[image]

did i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer escapes any HTML when data-binding for security reasons.
You would have to manually set the contents when the response comes in. Something like:

```
<core ajax ... on-core-response="{{handleResponse}}"></core-ajax>
<div id="content"></div>

...

Polymer({
   ...
   handleResponse: function (e) {
     this.injectBoundHTML(e.detail.response[0].content, this.$.content);
   }
});
```

See [official docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#boundhtml) for more information about this.